# How to get values from request object?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm trying to get a the session username using `request().username()`. In my secured class I have overridden the `getUsername()` to get the email key like this:

```
 public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {

@Override
public String getUsername(Context ctx){
    return ctx.session().get("email");
}

@Override
public Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx){
    return redirect(routes.Application.login());
}
```

At the login, I set the session:

```
    public static Result authenticate(){
    Form<Login> loginForm = Form.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();

    if(loginForm.hasErrors()){
        return badRequest(login.render(loginForm));
    }
    else{
        session().clear();
        session("email",loginForm.get().email);
        return redirect(routes.Application.problems());
    }

}
```

I can see this working because in my browser, when I login, I have this:

`""37fbf73f635e5f6a37323396add131da2b7cbcf6-email=bob@example.com""`

But, when I use the request().username() here, I get a null value.

```
public static Result addProblem(){


    create("new", "new", "new", "new", "new", request().username());
    return redirect(routes.Application.problems());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is where](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Security.java#L43) the value of `request.username()` is set in Play.

So in the controller(s) that you want secured, are you adding the `@Security.Authenticated(Security.class)` annotation? [Like this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Projects.java#L16)

Basically it's using [action composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaActionsComposition) to set the username on the `request()` before each request to your controller actions. In your example, the following should work:

```
@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
public class Problems extends Controller {

  public static Result addProblem() { 
    create("new", "new", "new", "new", "new", request().username());
    return redirect(routes.Application.problems());
  }

  ...
}
```

Follow [this sample project](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.2.x/samples/java/zentasks) for more.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that you can use `session().get("email")` instead of `request().username()` although, I was following the play documentation and it uses the latter here:

```
public static Result add() {
Project newProject = Project.create(
    "New project",
    form().bindFromRequest().get("group"),
    **request().username()**
);
return ok(item.render(newProject));
}
```